# jquery, find next element by class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How can i find the next element by class.

i tried with `$(obj).next('.class');` but this returns classes only in `$(obj)` parent. 
I need to take the next element anywhere throughout the code by class name.
Because my code looks like

```
<table>
<tr><td><div class="class">First</div></td></tr>
<tr><td><div class="class">Second</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

In this case you need to go up to the `<tr>` *then* use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), like this:

```
$(obj).closest('tr').next().find('.class');
```

Or if there may be rows in-between without the `.class` inside, you can use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), like this:

```
$(obj).closest('tr').nextAll(':has(.class):first').find('.class');
```

Comment: It would be easier to do this: $(obj).closest('tr').nextAll('.class')[0];

Comment: @StuR - that wouldn't work here, since .nextAll() only looks at sibling elements. You need something that looks at descendants to find the next <div> the question wants.

Comment: And what if wanted to get an attribute from that HTMLObject returned? Like an `$(obj).closest('tr').nextAll('.class')[0].attr('data-attribute');`

Comment: You may also need to use: **.parent().next("")** if the element has no siblings

Answer (score 30):

To find the next element with the same class:

```
$(".class").eq( $(".class").index( $(element) ) + 1 )
```

Answer (score 20):

You cannot use next() in this scenario, if you look at the **[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** it says:

*Next() Get the* ***immediately following sibling of each element*** *in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling that matches the selector.*


so if the second DIV was in the same TD then you could code:

```
// Won't work in your case
$(obj).next().filter('.class');
```

But since it's not, I don't see a point to use next(). You can instead code:

```
$(obj).parents('table').find('.class')
```

Comment: But how does it find next element.
.find would return all elements.

Comment: You got the parent that has both elements, and now you can search the element you want. I just helped me

Answer (score 0):

Given a first selector: **SelectorA**, you can find the next match of **SelectorB** as below:

Example with mouseover to change border-with:

```
$("SelectorA").on("mouseover", function() {
    var i = $(this).find("SelectorB")[0];
    $(i).css({"border" : "1px"});
    });
}
```

General use example to change border-with:

```
var i = $("SelectorA").find("SelectorB")[0];
$(i).css({"border" : "1px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

To find next element by tag name

```
  function findNext(start, tag)
    {
      while(start.nodeName !== tag)
      {
            start = start.nextElementSibling;
      }
      return start;
    }
```