# Find next element by class in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Firstly I have gone through some questions having same title as mine like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670136/jquery-find-next-element-by-class) etc. but none solved my problem.

**HTML** part -

```
<tr id="row_question_container">
    <td valign="top" colspan="2">
        <div id="at_test_area-1" class="at_test_area">
            <div id="at_questions_container">
                <div id="1" class="question_block completed unmarked" style="display: none;">
                <!-- Question / Option / Settings etc in nested tables are here -->
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="question_block completed marked">
                <!-- Question / Option / Settings etc in nested tables are here -->
                </div>
                <div id="3" class="question_block incomplete unmarked" style="display: none">
                <!-- Question / Option / Settings etc in nested tables are here -->
                </div>
                <div id="4" class="question_block incomplete unmarked" style="display: none">
                <!-- Question / Option / Settings etc in nested tables are here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get next/closet `id` of `div` (to navigate using next and previous buttons) having class `incomplete` or `marked`. After reading through similar questions, I tried following **jQuery**, but it returned `undefined`

```
var marked_question = $('#at_questions_container').next('.marked').attr('id');
alert(marked_question);
```

Comment: The problem is that you're working from the container level, whereas `next()` works on siblings, so you should look at the current visible child element and use `next()` on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For descendants you should use [**find()**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) or [**children()**](https://api.jquery.com/children/) depending on how deep you wish to go

```js
var marked_question = $('#at_questions_container').find('.marked').attr('id');
console.log(marked_question);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr id="row_question_container">
    <td valign="top" colspan="2">
        <div id="at_test_area-1" class="at_test_area">
            <div id="at_questions_container">
                <div id="1" class="question_block completed unmarked" style="display: none;">
                <!-- Question / Option / Settings etc in nested tables are here -->
                </div>
                <div id="2" class="question_block completed marked">
                <!-- Question / Option / Settings etc in nested tables are here -->
                </div>
                <div id="3" class="question_block incomplete unmarked" style="display: none">
                <!-- Question / Option / Settings etc in nested tables are here -->
                </div>
                <div id="4" class="question_block incomplete unmarked" style="display: none">
                <!-- Question / Option / Settings etc in nested tables are here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it, but then since this will return the first `marked` only how to navigate to next/closest marked?

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari, after using `find` you can use `next` like `$('#at_questions_container').find('.marked').next('.marked')`

Comment: I tested `.next('.marked')`, but I think it's returning as object, In console I got output as - `[div#3.question_block.incomplete.marked, div#4.question_block.incomplete.marked, prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[3], context: document]`

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari, right, if you want the id you need to include the `attr('id')` like `$('#at_questions_container').find('.marked').next('.marked').attr('id')`

Comment: sorry, that was my mistake, I knew but it didn't strike me. But I am still facing hard time on how to navigate back and forth... for better understanding, I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atultiwari/nva1uo3g/),if you please look where am I doing wrong, because next marked is returning undefined...

Comment: anyways tried so hard but was unable to figure out how to make Next and Previous navigation work. But I learned at least two things from your answers. I will close this question now, and ask separately about navigation. Thanks, Upvoted and selected.

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari, so sorry, I am in the middle of work right now. If you still dont figure it out let me know and I can help you later today or tommorow

Comment: Hi, I tried my best to create navigation buttons, but couldn't. Stuck since last 5 days. When you get some free time, will you please look into my newly ask question - [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326796/navigate-next-or-previous-div-by-class-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `next()` function will look for **siblings** of `#at_questions_container`, rather than child elements.

Since you're looking for a child of `#at_questions_container`, you should use the [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) function instead, in combination with the [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector:

```
var theID = $('#at_questions_container').children('.marked:first').attr('id');
```

Using `children()` is a much safer approach, since it will only search one depth, thus preventing any sub-elements which also have a class of `.marked` from being returned. For example, from the jQuery docs:

> The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only
>   travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse
>   down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren,
>   etc.) as well.

---

As a slight post-script to the above, the use of the `:first` selector is not essential. When calling `attr('id')`, jQuery will automatically return the ID attribute of the first element in the collection.

Comment: `:first` is not really needed since when you call `attr('id')` it will get the first one by default

Comment: That's true, but I included it rather out of education than anything.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but then since this will return the first marked only how to navigate to next/closest marked?

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari Next / closest to *what*?

Comment: I meant next marked element/div, but anyways I got that from another comment that I will have to use `next('.marked')` in the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var marked_question = $('#at_questions_container').find('.marked:first').attr('id');
```

You want to find descendants of at_questions_container and the first selector will give you the first one found. next works on sibling elements.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var marked_question =$('#at_questions_container').find('.marked').first().attr('id');
alert(marked_question);
```

Comment: And how do you get from `first()` to the next one? Please be more specific.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: var marked_question =$('#at_questions_container').find('.marked').first(); var nextValue = marked_question.next().attr('id'); console.log(nextValue);

Comment: Edit your answer and put that code there, not in a comment. It will improve the value of your answer (plus it will be more readable). Also, consider adding an explanation. Code only answers are discouraged on SO.