# jQuery how does one peek ahead in each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to find a definite answer for this. Consider the following:

```
var dupe = false;
    $(".syndUID").sort(function(a,b) {
        return a - b;
    }).each(function(i, el) {
        alert($(this).val() + " - " + $(this).next().val());
        if($(this).val() == $(this).next().val()) {
                dupe = true;
                return;
        };
    });
```

This code is an attempt to find duplicate values in a set of inputs with the class `syndUID`. They are scattered about a form, so not next to eachother in the DOM.

`next().val()` is always undefined though. am I using the wrong function? How do I simply peek ahead to the next element? I have access to the index, but I don't know how to even make use of it.

EDIT:

After reading the comments and answers I realized there really is no proper iterator in jQuery, which seems really stupid to me since it provides each(). I also had another bug with the above code. Here is the final solution I used that works:

```
// duplicate check
    var dupe = false;
    var prevVal = undefined;
    $(".syndUID").sort(function(a,b) {
        return $(a).val() - $(b).val();
    }).each(function() {
        if($(this).val() == prevVal) {
            dupe = true;
            return false;
        }
        prevVal = $(this).val();
    });
```

For anyone who finds this via google, the answers provided by others may be a decent alternative solution, but for my needs I found this sufficed.

Comment: `next()` will get the next sibling element, not necessarily the next element in the matched set.

Comment: So we get to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670136/jquery-find-next-element-by-class.

Comment: You only want to know if there are duplicate values? At least that's what the code implies (for me)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? there are many options, as well as many unknowns for us. Can there be more than 1 duplicate, are you just trying to warn the user if there is a duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like `$('.syndUID')[i+1]` to regrab the list, focusing on that element (and optionally turning it back into a jQuery object)

Using `[i+1]` will return a DOM element, but you can use `.eq(i+1)` to return a jQuery object. Or if you hate your future developers, wrap the DOM element in `$()` because screw readability!

As Andreas stated -- regrabbing the list is wasting memory. Before the loop, cache the object into a variable with `var element = $('.syndUID')` so you're not iterating the DOM so much.

Comment: So for each element in `$('.syndUID')` you're going to fetch all the elements with class `syndUID` again? O.o  `var elements = $('.syndUID'); elements.each(function(i, el) { var nextElement = elements.eq(i + 1); ... }`

Comment: That is an kinda a clunky method to keep grabbing the same list. Set it to a var, and then apply the indexing to the variable so that you keep the list cached - adding or removing from the list as needed.

Answer (score -1):

`next()` grabs the next sibling - not the next ancestor or parent.

For example, if we have an unordered list, next() works like this:

```
var a = $('#listone.first').next().val();
console.log(a) //outputs "Second"

<ul id="listone">
<li class="first">First</li>
<li class="second">Second</li>
</ul>
<ul id="listtwo">
<li class="third">Third</li>
<li class="fourth">Forth</li>
</ul>
```

So, if you are trying to grab the next parent, .val() applied to .next() wont work. I dont know what your outputting to (table, UL, DIV, etc) so it is hard to give you a working solution - but that is likely your problem. You are not traversing the DOM properly.

Comment: A valid observation however this doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: Yes, I know. I need to know the structure of what he/she is trying to grab values from so that I can edit my answer with a solution to his/her problem. I am just pointing out the problem with his approach to grabbing element values. This should probably be a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, you have your sorted array already, maybe instead of trying to do this with `.each()` you just use a simple `for` loop?

```
var elemArray = $(".syndUID").sort(function(a,b) {
    return a - b;
});

for(var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++){
    if(elemeArray[i].value == elemArray[i+1].value){
       //do something with comparison
    }
}
```

However, this will only check for a duplicate in the next `syndUID` element in the array. In order to do a complete search you would need to check each element against every element (excluding itself) from the array. That would involve a nested loop which will add an order of n^2 to your function

Comment: I wrote exactly that, except you (for some reason) omitted the alert OP had put in place. You're not even setting the `dupe` flag.

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ This site is not to completely re-write code. Just trying to point the OP in the right direction.