# How to affect only a first next specific div

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='images'></div>
<div class='toload'></div>
<div class='sky'></div>
<select class="select01">
    <option value="winners_02/2015.php">2015 - DOPS 6</option>
    <option value="winners_02/2014.php">2014 - DOPS 5</option>
    <option value="winners_02/2013.php">2013 - DOPS 4</option>
</select>

<div class='images'></div>
<div class='sea'></div>
<div class='toload'></div>  // target
```

JS

```
$('.select01').change(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();
    //something like: next().first(`toload`).load(a);
});
```

I have various situations before and after each of `select01`.
Changing the `select01` I need to affect only on first next div named `toload`.
In the above example it is marked by `target`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670136/jquery-find-next-element-by-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and match only first one:

```
$(this).nextAll('.toload').first().load(a);
```

Or **if there is no other** (*not like in your specific case*) `.toLoad` sibling of specific clicked `.select01`, then use:

```
$(this).siblings('.toload').load(a);
```

Comment: in his markup there 2 element with class `toload` one before select the other after i think you need to use `.next()` because he wants the next one. OP says `first next div named toload`

Comment: @guradio Ya thx! I missed it but still keep second example which still stipulate that `if there is no other .toLoad sibling`